# Sound output randomly switches or turns off while connected via HDMI

Tags: 18.04, sound, hdmi, monitor, external-monitor

I use Ubuntu 18.04. I have a monitor which is connected via `HDMI` to my computer. This monitor has a headphone input:

[image]

When I choose the `HDMI/DisplayPort-Built-in Audio` everything works as expected during only 3-5 minutes and after approximately that time the output switches to another one or just turns off while being selected. To overcome this problem I need again go to settings and select `HDMI` sound output. And then the same pattern repeats.

Worth noting that I see this problem (a random switching) only with `HDMI` output.

How can I solve it?
I tried to reinstall some packages (and reboot) but it didn't help me:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils --reinstall
```

Comment: When this happens, you see something new at the end of `journalctl -p warning -x`? Try first with `| grep pulse`.